# How to work with the lightning design system CSS framework

Tags: slds

I was asked by an employer to create a basic web page using Javascript, HTML, CSS, and to use the lightning design system CSS framework.

I'm completely new to salesforce and I was wondering how would I be able to use the SLDS CSS framework?

Am I able to use it in visual studio code or do I have to work from the salesforce platform?

Any resources would be gladly appreciated, I tried doing research on my own but the salesforce documentation is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any platform you desire. Start by going to the [Downloads](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/downloads/) page, download the source or precompiled CSS. Import it just as you would any other style sheet. By
default, you don't need a scope, just start using CSS.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- your markup here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Using the "min" version is recommended for production use, or you can use the standard file for debugging/easier reading.

If you need a "slds" scope (useful for limiting SLDS to just part of a page), use the scoping tool found on the downloads page.